# PHP - Simplify Way of Handling Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

When dealing with arrays I am forced to add a bunch of repetitive code to handle arrays with one child versus multiple:

```
//If more than one step, process each step, elcse processs single
        if(!array_key_exists('command',$pullcase['steps']['step'])) {
            foreach($pullcase['steps']['step'] as $step) {
                $command=$step['command'];
                $parameter=$step['parameter'];
                if(isset($step['value'])){ 
                    $value = $step['value']; 
                    $this->runCommands($command,$parameter,$value); 
                } else { 
                    $this->runCommands($command,$parameter); 
                }
            }
        } else {
            $command = $pullcase['steps']['step']['command'];
            $parameter = $pullcase['steps']['step']['parameter'];
            if(isset($pullcase['steps']['step']['value'])){ 
                $value = $pullcase['steps']['step']['value']; 
                $this->runCommands($command,$parameter,$value); 
            }
            else { $this->runCommands($command,$parameter); }
        }
```

As you can see, I'm having to duplicate my efforts depending on if there is a single item in an array versus multiple:

```
$pullcase['steps']['step'][0]['command']
```

vs

```
$pullcase['steps']['step']['command']
```

**How can I simplify this code so that I can use a single variable for all instances?**

Comment: Move the repetitive code into a separate function

Comment: Also, if you control the creation of the array, make `step` an array of one even if there is only one so you always have an array.  Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not following Abra - there can be mutliple [step] within [steps], this is theh nature of the array. Why would I want have only one [step] under [steps]? Also, numbering the steps would only serve to over-complicate the array.

Comment: You either have a `step` array `[step][0][command]` or you have a single step  `[step][command]`.  What I'm saying is when you create the array instead of  `[step][command]` make it  `[step][0][command]`.  Standard way of doing it, problem solved as you only need the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the creation of the array, make `step` an array of one even if there is only one so you always have an array. Is that possible?

You either have a `step` array `[step][0][command]` or you have a single step `[step][command]`. So when you create the array instead of `[step][command]` make it `[step][0][command]` etc. Standard way of doing it, problem solved as you only need the `foreach`.

If you can't do it at array creation then consider doing it before the loop:

```
if(is_array($pullcase['steps']['step'])) {
    $steps = $pullcase['steps']['step'];
} else {
    $steps[] = $pullcase['steps']['step'];
}
foreach($steps as $step) {
    $value = isset($step['value']) ? $step['value'] : null;
    $this->runCommands($step['command'], $step['parameter'], $value); 
}
```

Also, if `runCommands()` can detect a empty argument, then an alternative to the `if/else` for the function call is used above.

Comment: I agree that changing the array is the way to go. I'm creating the array from an object so I'll have to work on doing that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: thanks for the $value tip as well. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The following may help. It doesn't do much but call the function "runcommands" on a value if the key is 'command'. I am using it to show how you can use array_walk_recursive to possibly solve your problem.

First, you need the function to use:

```
function runcommandswhencommand($value, $key)
{
  if($key == 'command') runcommands($value);
}
```

Now, you can use the recursive walk on your array:

```
array_walk_recursive($pullcase, 'runcommandswhencommand');
```

With this, whenever the key is 'command', the value of that index will be used in the parameter of the function runcommands().

Comment: I like this technique. I'm unfamiliar with this function. I'll try it out and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to make it very simple. I hope it is obvious that you can tell it what to do based on the key value. I'm not sure if it will get what you need, but it is where I would start.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the nature of the array this won't work. The components of step are dependent on each other. Writing the logic around this function would be overkill. Thanks, though!